# Universal links partial exclude iOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I have included my path : `mydomain.com` to universal links as well as `mydomain.com/jobs`. From outside the app I want to redirect to the app when click on the link. However there is a need from within the app to open some web versions of the app. So some specific jobs like `mydomain.com/jobs?id=xxxx` are opening the webview but these are too connected with the deep linking. Is there a way to exclude some specific job requests ? For example adding an additional url parameter like `mydomain.com/jobs?id=xxxx?allowWebview=true.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html):

> To specify an area that should not be handled as a universal link, add “NOT ” (including a space after the T) to the beginning of the path string.

So you might want to try something like

```
"paths": ["mydomain.com/*", "NOT mydomain.com/*?allowWebview=true*"]
```

Comment: sorry I am a bit confused with how this works. Is this located in xcode? I can see that the app has associate domains with two paths in my xcode: www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com.

Comment: You should really read the whole document I linked above. It explains how to host an `apple-app-site-association` file at your domain, since that's how iOS knows to open those URLs in your app and not in mobile Safari.

Comment: Thank you for the link. My understanding was that the process happened only on the iOS app. From what I read I need to change the AASA file on the website and exclude the path. Then just pass the URL with parameter from the app.

Comment: Yes, but one thing is that universal links are only for incoming links, like links that the user taps on in the mail app, and not for links that you are opening programmatically inside your app by calling `openURL`. If this answers your question could you mark the answer correct?

Comment: well once i try to open the url the app opens again automatically. this is related to openUrl from appdelegate i guess, I thought it was related with the universal links